# Why can't I see the result of foo_b(2) and foo_c(3)?

Tags: c++

I do not understand why the debug console result is like this.

After debugging, Visual Studio's debug console shows:

```
FOOEY2
Hello World!
It's Over 9000!
```

I thought the result will be `FOOEY241.5`

Why can't I see the result of `foo_b(2)` and `foo_c(3)`, even though these methods are called?

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
#include "misc.h"

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void foo();

int main() {

    foo();
    foo_a(1);
    foo_b(2);
    foo_c(3);

    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "It's Over " << POWERLEVEL << "!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

void foo() {
    std::cout << "FOOEY";
}
```

**a.h**

```cpp
void foo_a(int x);
```

**a.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void foo_a(int x) {
    std::cout << x + 1 << std::endl;
}
```

**b.h**

```cpp
int foo_b(int x);
```

**b.cpp**

```cpp
int foo_b(int x) {
    int a = x * 2;
    return a;
}
```

**c.h**

```cpp
float foo_c(int x);
```

**c.cpp**

```cpp
float foo_c(int x) {
    return x / 2;
}
```

**misc.h**

```cpp
const int POWERLEVEL = 9000;
```

Comment: `foo_b(2);` returns an int but you are not saving the return value anywhere so the compiler notices that you don't use the result and doesn't call the function.  And similar with `foo_c(3);`  Us the result by `std::cout << foo_b(2) << std::endl;` and you will see the number printed.  Or cout the value inside foo_b like you do with foo_a.

Comment: "*so the compiler notices that you don't use the result and doesn't call the function*" - I **seriously** doubt that.  But whether it does or not, it is true that the return values of `foo_b()` and `foo_c()` are simply not being printed to `cout`, which is why they are not shown in the debug output.

Comment: Ohh I got it thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

foo_b and foo_c are actually been called, but they only return a value, they don't have any cout<<something.
For that reason you cannot see the result.